# Remove reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I am working on a javascript-application with AngularJS.
Currently I have a variable wich is referenced to a second one and third one.
In my case I want to remove the reference to the second one, but keep the reference to the third one.

So, my question: How to remove a reference between two variables in javascript / Angular?

Some code examples:

```
// $builder.forms['default'] is the object wich will be changed
// $scope.tree is my own variable
$scope.tree = $builder.forms['default'];
```

`$builder.forms['default']` is binded to `$scope.tree` and watched by another controller (not relevant to show).

This code will customize the `$builder.forms['default']`:

```
$scope.navigateToChildren = function(formObjects) {
        $builder.forms['default'].splice.apply(
            $builder.forms['default'], [
              0, $builder.forms['default'].length
            ].concat(formObjects.children)
        );
};
```

In this case I want to remove to reference to `$scope.tree` but keep it watched by the other controller.

Please let me know if it's unclear...

Comment: You mean two objects ?

Comment: What do you mean by referenced? Variables containing the same object references?

Comment: Please write some code demonstrating your problem.

Comment: could you show your code?

Comment: Added some code... Hope it's more clear

Answer (score 3):

You remove a reference to an object by setting the variable or property that holds the reference to any other value or, in the case of a property, by removing the property.

So, if you have two objects:

```
var a = {};
var b = {};
```

And, then you assign a reference to `b` to a property in `a` like this:

```
a.bRef = b;
```

Then, `a` now holds a reference to the object point to by `b`.  If you now clear `b`.

```
b = null;
```

Now, there is only once reference to `b` in `a.bRef`.  If you wanted to clear that last remaining reference to the object that was originally pointed to by `b` so it would then be eligible for garbage collection, you could do any of these:

```
a.bRef = null;
delete a.bRef;
a.bRef = "something else";
```

Any of these would make the object originally pointed to by `b` unreachable by any live code.  Thus, that object would be eligible for garbage collection in the next GC cycle.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I don't think it is working because in my case `a.bRef = null` will unset the watchers who are on that variable...

Comment: @Bob - I wrote this answer before you added angular-specific code examples to the question.  It now sounds like you're asking an angular specific watcher question, not a JS reference question which is what the original question looked like.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to do that. The real question is still to remove a reference. But the problem that appears is Angular (it's watchers). Sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy

And when you use Angular, you can use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already tried  `angular.copy()` but didn't work because I need to KEEP the `watchers` and REMOVE the reference ;)